# WP Meta Query at depth 2

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, meta-query

I'm interested in doing a meta query according to some post data that doesn't exist at the first level of the post meta. In other words, I would need two or more keys to get to the variable I'm interested in querying by. Is this possible?

Specifically I'm interested in querying by `["woocommerce_booking_settings"][0]["booking_specific_date"]` in this excerpt of post meta below:

```
...

["_upsell_ids"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(6) "a:0:{}"
}
["_crosssell_ids"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(6) "a:0:{}"
}
["_product_version"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(5) "2.6.1"
}
["_product_image_gallery"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(0) ""
}
["woocommerce_booking_settings"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=> {
    ["booking_specific_date"]=>
    array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "30-6-2016"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "8-7-2016"
    }
}
...
```

Comment: it's not possible directly with `WP_Query`. but you can write a plugin which create another meta in the product each time the product is saved. and then you can use this new meta in `WP_Query` (or `get_posts`)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how Woocommerce saves this, but what does it look like in the database postmeta table?